# Get great grand parent folder path (three levels up) in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Is there an elegant way to get the (great-grandparent folder) three levels up from a folder path?

I'm only looking to get `C:\folderA\folderB` from the full path, but both solutions just seem ugly to me.

```
$path = "C:\folderA\folderB\folderC\FolderD\folderE"

# option 1
(Get-Item $path).parent.parent.parent.FullName

# option 2    
$path | Split-Path -Parent | Split-Path -Parent | Split-Path -Parent
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (works only if the path exists):

```
(Get-Item "$path\..\..\..").FullName
```

Alternatively, if the path does not exist:

```
[System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath("$path\..\..\..")
```

You could also use this generic option for `n` levels:

```
[System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($path + "\.." * $n)
```

Comment: You might want to try a `Test-Path` before you actually switch to it.  On my machines that shows the root drive even though I don't have multiple levels of subdirectories so use this answer with caution if you are not the OP.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could use a wrapper function... not exactly ideal but a little fun:

```
function Split-PathLots {
    [CmdletBinding()]

    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]
        $Path
        ,
        [int]
        $NumberOfTimes = 1
    )

    Process {
        $PathToReturn = $Path
        Write-Verbose "Input = $Path"

        [int]$i = 1
        while ($i -le $NumberOfTimes) {
            $PathToReturn = $PathToReturn | Split-Path -Parent
            Write-Verbose "($i/$NumberOfTimes) $PathToReturn"
            $i++
        }

        return $PathToReturn
    }
}

$path = "C:\folderA\folderB\folderC\FolderD\folderE"

Write-Output (Split-PathLots -Path $path -NumberOfTimes 3 -Verbose)
```

## output

```
VERBOSE: Input = C:\folderA\folderB\folderC\FolderD\folderE
VERBOSE: (1/3) C:\folderA\folderB\folderC\FolderD
VERBOSE: (2/3) C:\folderA\folderB\folderC
VERBOSE: (3/3) C:\folderA\folderB
C:\folderA\folderB
```

Comment: Looks good. I would add some tweaks though and definitely use different names for the function/parameter names.

Comment: Twas only thrown together in a couple of mins `;-)` But yes, I agree, it's not the best named! If you have some suggestions I could update the code in my answer