# Extract "subpath" of a given path

Tags: powershell

I am trying to modify a path to report in a log, and I want to show a string indicating the leaf, parent folder name, and grandparent folder name. It's enough to understand the path in this context, and the full path can be really long and hard to format for logging.

For example, given a path of

```
C:\FolderA\FolderB\FolderC\FolderD\FolderE\File.txt
```

I want:

```
\FolderD\FolderE\File.txt
```

So, I have this that works

```
$testIsValidPath.pathForLog = "...\$(Split-Path (Split-Path (Split-Path $path -parent) -parent) -leaf)\$(Split-Path (Split-Path $path -parent) -leaf)\$(Split-Path $path -leaf)"
```

But this seems inelegant. Is there a better way that is PS version agnostic?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52183213/get-great-grand-parent-folder-path-three-levels-up-in-powershell) is a way!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get great grand parent folder path (three levels up) in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52183213/get-great-grand-parent-folder-path-three-levels-up-in-powershell)

Comment: I should clarify, since all the solutions mentioned go the wrong direction. Given a path of C:\FolderA\FolderB\FolderC\FolderD\FolderE\File.txt I want ...\FolderD\FolderE\File.txt not C:\FolderA\FolderB\FolderC. Now, it occurs to me that I could do this with a replace; go back as far as I want, get the path from there back to root, then replace that with ... in the original full path. Not as straight forward as I was thinking, but better than the nasty I have. ;)

Comment: The title or your question is misleading. Basically the opposite of what you want. I'll have a shot at improving it.

Comment: `@("...") + ($Path -Split "\\")[-3..-1] -Join "\"` or: `@("...") + $Path.Split("\")[-3..-1] -Join "\"`